# SignalR Chat applicatoin in Vb.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, vb.net, import

I'm developing a sample chat application in vb.net using `SignalR`
Could anyone please guide me.

I have created a sample chat application:
please find the code below:

```
Imports Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR
Imports Microsoft.Owin.Hosting
Imports Owin
Imports Microsoft.Owin.Cors

Public Class Form1


    Private Sub BtnSubmit_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BtnSubmit.Click

        Dim connection = New HubConnection("http://localhost:8080")
        Dim myHub = connection.CreateHubProxy("myHubProxy")
        Dim commonhub As String = connection.myhub
        connection.Start().Wait()    


    End Sub
End Class
```

I'm unable to add hubconnection.vb file as it is throwing some error.
where i have class for Connection, Proxy start and send function.

Comment: You want to import `Imports Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Client` not the `Imports Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR` unless you're making a hub. Search on Nuget for SignalR .NET Client.

Comment: Thanks yes i have imported the Nuget. And when i import 'Imports Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Client' its throwing error:-(

Comment: in java script client code we have                                                                  // Call the Send method on the hub. chat.server.send($('#displayname').val(), $('#message').val()); to send the data but im not sure how to do that in VB.Net

Comment: Could you please help me on this

Comment: `myHub.Invoke("MethodName", Parameters)`

Comment: Could you please share any sample code in vb.net for SignalR chat

Comment: I'm not sure how make Hub Connection and broadcast the data to the common hub from the button click event in my vb .net application